# DB design without passing around jdbc

Tags: java, design-patterns, jdbc, java-8

I have a db design issue that I am facing with one of my projects. I am trying to implement a service and part of that service is a db layer. It is setup such that I have helper classes that perform get/update methods to the database and a layer on top of them that is a janitor. For ex:

```
public class GetStudentDBHelper {
   public List<Student> get(List<Integer> ids) {
      Conn getConnection...
      // run sql query and construct returning Student objects
   }
   public List<Student> get(List<Classroom> byClassroom) {
      // get all students in passed in classrooms
      // run sql query and construct returning Student objects
   }
}

public class StudentJanitor {
   public GetStudentDBHelper getStudentDBHelper;
   public UpdateStudentDBHelper updateStudentDBHelper;
   public UpdateClassroomDBHelper updateClassroomDBHelper;

   public List<Student> getStudents(List<Integer> ids) {
       return getStudentDBHelper.get(ids);
   }

   public void saveStudents(List<Students> students, int classRoomid) {
       Connection conn = Pool.getConnection(); // assume this gives a jdbc
       conn.autocommit(false);

       try {
           try 
           {
              updateStudentDBHelper.saveForClassroom(students, classRoomid, conn);
              updateClassroomDBHelper.markUpdated(classRoomid, conn);
              conn.commit();
           }
           catch
           {
              throw new MyCustomException(ErrorCode.Student);
           }
       }
       catch (SQLException c)
       {
           conn.rollback();
       }
       finally {
           conn.close();
       }
}

public class ClassroomJanitor{
   public void saveClassRoon(List<Classrooms> classrooms) {
       Connection conn = Pool.getConnection()// assume this gives a jdbc
       conn.autocommit(false);

       try {

           try {
              updateClassroomDBHelper.save(classrooms, conn);
              updateStudentDBHelper.save(classrooms.stream().map(Classroom::getStudents).collect(Collections.toList()), conn);
              conn.commit();
           }
           catch {
              throw new MyCustomException(ErrorCode.ClassRoom);
           }
       }
       catch (SQLException c)
       {
           conn.rollback();
       }
       finally {
           conn.close();
       }
}...

public class GetClassroomDBHelper{}...
public class UpdateClassroomDBHelper{}...
```

The update db classes all compose multiple other updators in case they need to update values in other tables (ie. saving a student means I have to touch a classroom table in which a student belongs to update its last updated time for instance).

The issue I am having is for the update db classes, I have to pass in a connection from my Janitor class if i am touching multiple tables in order to have transactions and their rollback capabilities. See above for what I mean. Is there a better way to do this? This type of try, catch, pass in conn to db helpers, will have to be done for any multi transaction operation in my janitors.

In short, you can see that the code is generally like this duplicated across multiple methods:

```
       Connection conn = Pool.getConnection()// assume this gives a jdbc
       conn.autocommit(false);

       try {

           try {
              //do some business logic requiring Connection conn
           }
           catch {
              throw new MyCustomException(ErrorCode);
           }
       }
       catch (SQLException c)
       {
           conn.rollback();
       }
       finally {
           conn.close();
       }
```

Comment: Well, you can have one method that does the try-catch-rollback-commit thing, and you pass a `Runnable` or a similar functional interface to it which calls whatever methods that need the connection. But why aren't you using something like Hibernate to manage your database and logic?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am sort of limited in how I do my database to basically only raw connections (just a requirement). Can you give an example code of how that can be achieved?

Comment: I think using the template design pattern you will improve code readability and avoid the boilerplate

Comment: @Koitoer can you provide an example of how I can do that? I don't see it working since each db helper class has various methods with various types of input parameters. ie. the StudentDBHelper has a saveForClassroom that takes in List<Student>, classRoomid, conn and ClassroomDBHelper has a save that takes in List<Classroom> and conn. There is no consistency between what methods the helpers implement

Comment: That is something... I have seen even experienced programmers to run into this type of situations :P

Comment: The title says to me that you need a Singleton that hides JDBC, thereby effectively making it accessible "globally".  That is, it avoids having to pass it around, yet makes it available everywhere.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use Spring JDBC for that? http://www.journaldev.com/2603/spring-transaction-management-jdbc-example

Comment: @AlexeySoshin An unfortunate business requirement.

Comment: [Check This](https://github.com/JExaples/quicklooks/tree/master/jdbc-design-pattern-example)

Comment: I would seriously consider Spring JDBC.  It pretty much lets you have your cake and eat it.

Comment: You would probably want to consider using a `ThreadLocal` variable to pass connections around (assuming everything is going to be executed on the same thread). This way, the connection will be there when the DBHelpers need them without passing them through your layers. I think spring-jdbc does this for either it's connections or transaction management (could be wrong on this point)

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have a code sequence that is duplicated but it only differs in some parts you can use a [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

In your case I would introduce a `TransactionTemplate` class and use a callback interface for the parts that are different. E.g.

```
public class TransactionTemplate {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public TransactionTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSource);

    }

    public <T> T execute(TransactionCallback<T> transactionCallback) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();// assume this gives a jdbc
        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            T result = transactionCallback.doInTransaction(conn);
            conn.commit();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            conn.rollback();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The callback interface would look like this

```
public interface TransactionCallback<T> {
    public T doInTransaction(Connection conn) throws Exception;
}
```

As you can see the `TransactionTemplate` manages the transaction while the `TransactionCallback` implements the logic that must be done in one transaction.

Your client code will then look like this

```
public class StudentJanitor {

    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    StudentJanitor(DataSource dataSource) {
        transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void saveStudents(List<Students> students, int classRoomid) {
        SaveStudentsTransaction saveStudentsTransaction = new SaveStudentsTransaction(students, classRoomid);
        transactionTemplate.execute(saveStudentsTransaction);
    }

}
```

and the logic is placed in the TransactionCallback

```
public class SaveStudentsTransaction implements TransactionCallback<Void> {

    public GetStudentDBHelper getStudentDBHelper;
    public UpdateStudentDBHelper updateStudentDBHelper;
    public UpdateClassroomDBHelper updateClassroomDBHelper;

    private List<Students> students;
    private int classRoomid;

    public SaveStudentsTransaction(List<Students> students, int classRoomid) {
        this.students = students;
        this.classRoomid = classRoomid;
    }

    @Override
        public Void doInTransaction(Connection conn) throws Exception {
            try 
            {
               updateStudentDBHelper.saveForClassroom(students, classRoomid, conn);
               updateClassroomDBHelper.markUpdated(classRoomid, conn);
               conn.commit();
            }
            catch
            {
               throw new MyCustomException(ErrorCode.Student);
            }
            return null;
        }

}
```

Comment: So if I am following this correctly, I would need to have one class each for each operation I wish to perform using the transaction callback. ie. I would need an entire other class for UpdateStudentsTransaction and DeleteStudentsTransactions, etc. This will get super verbose real quick.

Answer (score 2):

Two main concerns you are currently facing are the boiler plate code for repetitive tasks related to connection (get/execute/close etc)
and infrastructure for getting the same connection across method boundaries. The first is typically solved using [Template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and the latter
using [Threadlocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variables to pass around appropriate connection across methods. These type of concerns have been solved in Java world long ago but 
will require you to rely on framework like Spring ([JDBC template](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)) etc which have this feature from last decade or so or you would need to roll out stripped
down version of this infrastructure. If you are interested in latter then you can take hint from similar attmepts shared on Github like [this](https://github.com/phil-bradley/jdbcwrapper).

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It is the correct answer but it's only lacking an example which can be found through the links?